# Can a rational Seifert surface have n boundary components?

Tags: surfaces, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I was wondering if it is possible for a knot to have a rational Seifert surface with 3 boundary components (pair of pants) and n many in general.What would such a knot look like?